# laravel pdo_connection mssql

Tags: php, laravel

Estou usando o laravel 5.6, no ubuntu 16 e estou tentando conectar ele no mssql 2012. Estou usando a biblioteca db_lib pois isso é requerimento do projeto. Quando tento conectar aparace esse erro:

```
 PDOException  : SQLSTATE[IM001]: Driver does not support this 
 function: driver does not support that attribute

 at /home/agner/Documentos/ubuntu-laravel/vendor/doctrine/dbal/lib/Doctrine/DBAL/Driver/PDOConnection.php:71

 public function getServerVersion()
 70|     {
 > 71|         return PDO::getAttribute(PDO::ATTR_SERVER_VERSION);
 72|     }

Exception trace:

1   PDO::getAttribute()
  /home/agner/Documentos/ubuntu-laravel/vendor/doctrine/dbal/lib/Doctrine/DBAL/Driver/PDOConnection.php:71

2 Doctrine\DBAL\Driver\PDOConnection::getServerVersion()
/home/agner/Documentos/ubuntu- laravel/vendor/doctrine/dbal/lib/Doctrine/DBAL/Connection.php:496
```